# Laravel 4 adding custom attributes to User Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using [this custom package](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/spinegar/laravelsugar) to integrate my SugarCRM into Laravel 4. I'm storing basic user info in my laravel database which I use to access the rest of the users data that is stored in Sugar.

For instance, I have the company name stored into my project database. I use that to find the website, email address, etc. which is stored in Sugar. I don't want duplicate info anywhere, so I figured I would just get the other necessary Sugar user data on the fly.

**The problem**: I was hoping to append the Sugar data retrieved to the `User Model` but it's proving difficult and apparently that was the intention of the creator. I'm doing this in my view:

```
@foreach ($users AS $user)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ URL::to('user/' . $user->id . '/edit') }}">{{ $user->username }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ $user->main_contact_c }}</td>
        <td><a href="mailto:{{ $user->email }}" target="_blank">{{ $user->email }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ $user->role }}</td>
        <td>[ Get From Sugar API ]</td>
        <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#confirm-user-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I know it's bad design to call model methods from  a view so I'm not sure how to properly access my custom data that pertains to each record. I could create the function `getMainContactCAttribute()` in the User Model but I can't pass info to the function in the view obviously...What are some legit things I can do?

Comment: Hi Jared. Sorry, but the User Model is coming from SugarCRM? Right? You should access to the custom fields of the User Model? It seems to me that you already do seeing the code that you specified ($user-> main_contact_c). Could you explain?

Comment: The User Model is native to Laravel, not related to SugarCRM at all. I just sent a different set of variables to the view as a workaround so I don't need this to work anymore.

Comment: I do not know very well the framework Lavarel, but I have read that it is possible to extend the User model and enrich it with attributes that contain data coming for example from SugarCRM.